# Intro Bio question: dihybrid punnet square

Tags: genetics, homework

Today we had our exam. There was a punnet square for two genes. and when I multiplied , for example, `Ry × rY` I wrote the answer as `RyrY`. When I returned back home I realized that I may have made a mistake because the book used to write them as `RrYy`. So is my answer write or wrong? why? I also freaked out because there were 16 boxes in the punnet square so does that mean that I'll lose 16 points? I got everything else in the exam correctly. So I'm freaking out because I don't know if I'm getting a 100 or 86 which will throw all my work the entire semester. Please respond as soon as you can. I feel like I'm having a panic attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hah! You can relax. There's no difference between `RyrY` and `RrYy`, as there is no fundamental ordering of genes like that. That being said, the standard convention would be to write `RrYy` (or at least `RryY`), so if your grader is a pedantic hardass they might take off a couple of points, but probably not the whole 16.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! I've been worrying so much. This literally made my day